# How to resize images without losing quality?

Tags: python, image-resizing

I'm having trouble with this for months, i downloaded an image and i tried to resize it to make it fit on a button, but when i run the program the bin photo is really pixelated and grainy not really sharp like the original. How to resize trying to keep it detailed similar to the original? The code and the image:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 
import customtkinter 
bin_png = customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('bin.png'), size=(30, 35)) 
button = customtkinter.CTkButton(win, image=bin_png , text='', width=20)
```

[image]

Comment: What is `win` in the code!?

Comment: "win" is the window i create, like "win = Tk()" to associate the button widget, any ideas to resize correctly ?

Comment: I suggest to resize the PIL image (i.e. the `Image.open('bin.png')` object). Forza Milan!